# Linux User Group Assignment

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems

So I'm trying to create a way for users in Linux to create groups, then add other users to them. As far as I can tell, only root can modify groups. The reason is, I want users to be able to create a group, then chgrp/chown the files they own and give read access to specified groups of users.

My idea was to make a utility that encapsulates a "sudo groupadd " call. This utility would have access to some root-accessible file that keeps track of group ownership. Is it possible to do this without needing the user to enter root password?

I know that this is probably very exploitable, but please note that this is not going into production of any sort.

Please let me know how I can accomplish my approach (namely letting non-sudo run sudo program) or if you have any alternative suggestions.

Comment: You can set the "suid" bit of an executable to have it run as root, but I wouldn't recommend it.

I'm not sure what your use case is. Is this for a learning environment (where students can try the commands)? If so, maybe a chroot could be an option.

Comment: Why not just use `sudo`.  `sudo` can restrict a group of users to run a single command, `groupadd` in your case, as root (not just all commands).  Check out the `sudoers` manual page.

Comment: I think the setuid flag would allow me to accomplish my design. I want to restrict users from having full sudo privileges, so I'm encapsulating the commands they can run into an executable.

Comment: I don't think I was quite clear, by default `sudo` allows you to run any command as root.  It can also be configured to allow a set of users to run a single command as root.  For example, you could configure `sudo` to allow user bill,bob,sue to run ONLY `groupadd` as root (no other commands would be permitted).

Comment: Ok cool, looking back at your comment I understand, I just misread it. Thanks!